# Explanation of function pointers

Tags: c++, function, pointers, typedef

I have a problem with understanding some C++ syntax combined with function pointers and function declarations, that is:

Usually when we want to declare a type of function we make something like:

```
typedef void(*functionPtr)(int);
```

and this is fine for me. From now on functionPtr is a type, that represents
pointer to the function, that returns void and takes int by a value as an argument.

We can use it as follows:

```
typedef void(*functionPtr)(int);

void function(int a){
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    functionPtr fun = function;
    fun(5);

    return 0;
}
```

And we get `5` printed on a screen.

we have got pointer to function `fun`, we assign some existing pointer to function - `function` and we execute this function by a pointer. Cool.

Now as I read in some books, function and pointer to function are treated somehow the same, so in fact after declaration of `function()` function everytime we say function we mean real function and pointer to function at the same type, so following compiles and every instruction gives the same result (5 printed on a screen):

```
int main() {

    functionPtr fun = function;
    fun(5);
    (*fun)(5);
    (*function)(5);
    function(5);

    return 0;
}
```

So now as long as I can imagine, that pointers to functions and functions are pretty much the same, then it's somehow fine for me.

Then I though, if pointer to function and real function is the same, then why cannot I do following:

```
typedef void(functionPtr)(int); //removed *

void function(int a){
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    functionPtr fun = function;
    fun(5);

    return 0;
}
```

This gives me following error:

> prog.cpp:12:14: warning: declaration of 'void fun(int)' has 'extern' and is initialized
>     functionPtr fun = function;

therefore I understood, that for some reason compiler now understands, that fun is **already existing** function. Then I tried following:

```
int main() {

    functionPtr fun;
    fun(5);

    return 0;
}
```

And I got linking error. I somehow understand, that as compiler now treats fun as already existing function, then due to the fact, that fun is nowhere defined, I will get linking error. Therefore I changed the name of the variable:

```
typedef void(functionPtr)(int);

void function(int a){
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    functionPtr function;
    function(5);

    return 0;
}
```

So now function in main shadows global name function, so `function(5)` is used from declaration `functionPtr function;` It works fine and prints 5 on the screen.

So now I am shocked. Why did this happen? Also misleading thing is, that when function pointer is declared like this:

```
typedef void(*functionPtr)(int);
```

i can create function of type functionPtr in following manner:

```
functionPtr function(int a){
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

whereas, when declaring something like:

```
typedef void(functionPtr)(int);
```

makes this:

```
functionPtr function(int a){
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

being interpreted by a compiler as function returning function. If this is so, why previous declaration (`typedef void(functionPtr)(int);`) knew, that this is a function returning void and not function returning functionPtr?

Could someone please explain what is really happening underhood for me?

I am using g++ C++ compiler with C++14 option enabled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, it is confusing a bit.

Function type and pointer to function type are indeed two different types (no more similar than `int` and pointer to `int`). However, there is a rule, that a function type **decays** to pointer to function type in almost all contexts. Here *decaying* loosely means *converted* (there is a difference between type conversion and decaying, but you are probably not interested in it right now).

What is important, is that **almost** every time you use a function type, you end up with pointer to function type. Note the almost, however - almost every time is not **always**!

And you are hitting some cases when it doesn't.

```
typedef void(functionPtr)(int);
functionPtr fun = function;
```

This code attempts to copy one function (not the pointer! the function!) to another. But of course, this is not possible - you can't copy functions in C++. The compiler doesn't allow this, and I can't believe you got it compiled (you are saying you got linker errors?)

Now, this code:

```
typedef void(functionPtr)(int);
functionPtr function;
function(5);
```

`function` does not shadow anything. Compiler knows it is not a function pointer which can be called, and just calls your original `function`.

Comment: this piece of code was not compiled. The piece of code, that was is :
`functionPtr fun;
    fun(5);` (no assignment)
Here fun is seen as some function, that somewhere exists, but linked cannot see it, so I get linking errors

Comment: So, why when `typedef void(functionPtr)(int);` is like this and I have:
functionPtr fun; fun(); I get linking errors? See here: https://ideone.com/e20FmU

Comment: @DawidPi Because of, as SergeyA well explained, that code is incorrect. Could only work in the case posted in this answer where `function` function is implemented. In your case fun is not.

Comment: so what does this line mean? : `functionPtr fun;`, when `typedef void(functionPtr)(int);`

Answer (score 4):

The most interesting of your examples is this one, reproduced here without the use of typedef:

```
void function(int a) { // declaration and definition of 'function'
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    void function(int); // declaration of 'function'
    function(5);
}
```

In most contexts in C++, the re-declaration of `function` in local scope would shadow the global `::function`. So expecting a linker-error there makes sense - `main()::function` has no definition right?

Except functions are special in this regard. From a note in [basic.scope.pdel]:

> Function declarations at block scope
>   and variable declarations with the extern specifier at block scope refer to declarations that are **members of
>   an enclosing namespace**, but they do not introduce new names into that scope.

So that code example is exactly equivalent to:

```
void function(int a) { /* ... */ }
void function(int ); // just redeclaring it again, which is ok

int main() {
    function(5);
}
```

You can also verify this by putting the global `function` into some namespace, `N`. At this point, the local scope declaration would add a name to `::`, but it wouldn't have a definition - hence you do get a linker error.

---

The other interesting thing you touched on is the notion of function-to-pointer conversion, [conv.func]:

> An lvalue of function type T can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The result is a pointer to
>   the function.

When you have a function call expression - if the thing you're calling is a function type, it is first converted to a pointer-to-function. That's why these are equivalent:

```
fun(5);         // OK, call function pointed to by 'fun'
(*fun)(5);      // OK, first convert *fun back to 'fun'
function(5);    // OK, first convert to pointer to 'function'
(*function)(5); // OK, unary* makes function get converted to a pointer
                // which then gets dereferenced back to function-type
                // which then gets converted back to a pointer
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's see your examples one by one, and what they really mean.

```
typedef void(functionPtr)(int);

void function(int a){
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    functionPtr fun = function;
    fun(5);

    return 0;
}
```

Here you are creating a typedef `functionPtr` for functions which take and `int`, and don't return values. `functionPtr` is not actually a typedef for a function pointer, but of an actual function.

Then you are trying to declare a new function `fun`, and assign to it `function`. Unfortunately you cannot assign to functions, so this does not work.

```
int main() {

    functionPtr fun;
    fun(5);

    return 0;
}
```

Again, you are declaring a function `fun` with the signature you specified. But you don't define it, so rightfully you fail the linking phase.

```
typedef void(functionPtr)(int);

void function(int a){
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    functionPtr function;
    function(5);

    return 0;
}
```

What happens here? You define the `typedef`, and in the main you write `functionPtr function;`. This basically is simply a prototype for the function you have already written, `function`. It restates that this function exists, but otherwise it does nothing. In fact, you can write:

```
typedef void(functionPtr)(int);

void function(int a){
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    functionPtr function;
    functionPtr function;
    functionPtr function;
    void function(int);

    function(5);

    return 0;
}
```

How many times you want, it won't change a thing. The `function(5)` you are calling after is always the same thing.

One thing you can do in C++ is to declare the prototype of a function using such a typedef, but you cannot define it in that way.

```
typedef void(*functionPtr)(int);

functionPtr function(int a){
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Here you are defining a function which returns a function pointer, but then you do not return it. The compiler, depending on your settings, may or may not complain. But again `function` is completely separated from `functionPtr`. You have essentially written

```
void (*)(int)   function(int a) {
    ...
}
```

The last example, the one where you have a function returning a function, is simply not allowed, because it would be meaningless.

Answer (score -1):

```
typedef void functionPtr (int);

void function (int a){
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    functionPtr *func;
    func = function;
    func(5);
    return 0;
}
```

You can use it in this way, I had tested.
There really a litter tricky about this issue.

Comment: This does not answer the question *why* this problem occurs. Please only add answers that differ from the previous ones or add some relevant points.