# How to set a function into a variable and call from it?

Tags: c++

I wonder if it is possible to do this in C ++?

e.g:

```
varFunction = void TestFunction();
RunCode(varFunction);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: What you're looking for are [function pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html).
If your functions might also be lambdas, functors or other stateful constructs, [`std::function`](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is the way to go.

Comment: Consider reading a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @PasserBy Well, that topic might be covered in the _advanced sections_ of these books.

Comment: @user0042 - Intermediate at most. Advanced features of C++ are slightly more involved then storing a pointer to a function.

Comment: Feel free to mark the good answers as useful and accept the one you think that answered your question.

Answer (score 5):

With C++11 and higher, you can use the [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) to store function pointers and function objects.

But storing [function pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) was available in C++ from the start. This means you can store the address of a function and call it later.

BTW, [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) are also very useful (and the [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) they are denoting could be assigned or passed as `std::function`-s)

---

Here is an example showing three different ways to achieve what did you asked for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void RunCode(const std::function<void()>& callable) {
    callable();
}

void TestFunction() {
    std::cout << "TestFunction is called..." << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::function<void()> varFunction_1 = TestFunction;
    void (*varFunction_2)() = TestFunction;

    RunCode(varFunction_1);
    RunCode(varFunction_2);
    RunCode([]() { std::cout << "TestLambda is called..." << std::endl; });

    return 0;
}
```

But this is just the tip of the iceberg, passing function pointers and function objects as parameters is very common in the [algorithms library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Comment: Inherited from C, I presume. You can do similar things in C.

Comment: C don't have yet any notion of lambda expressions or closures (but that might change in the future C20 standard). That requires the compiler to compute the set of closed values (in a lambda).

Answer (score 3):

C++ provides several ways to do it.

For example, you can use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) template: include `<functional>` and use the following syntax ([demo](http://ideone.com/UfqULT)):

```
std::function<void()> varFunction(TestFunction);
varFunction();
```

You can also use function pointers ([Q&A on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35654908/335858)).

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, you can declare a C-style function type as follows:

```
typedef int (*inttoint)(int);
```

This creates a type `inttoint` that can store any function that takes an int as parameter and returns an int. You can use it as follows.

```
// Define a function
int square(int x) { return x*x; }

// Save the function in sq variable
inttoint sq { square };

// Execute the function
sq(4);
```

---

Since C++11, these variables can also store lambda functions, like so

```
inttoint half { [](int x) { return x/2; } };
```

And use it same as above.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a lambda expression like this:

```
auto add = [](int a, int b) { return a+b; };
cout << add(10, 20) << endl; // Output: 30
```

More info about how lambda expressions work: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda