# Predicates in C++

Tags: c++

Predicate arguments in C++ STL algorithms are defined to be type arguments in template. Form what I understand, predicates can be either of two things -

1) *A structure with an overload of operator() returning bool. This can be used as a type in template argument for predicate*.

2) *A function returning bool. How is this a type parameter for predicate in template?*

Comment: Let us reverse the question - what do *you* see wrong with function being a type? A function is simply converted to a *function pointer* which will point to it

Comment: I'm pretty sure predicates are normal value arguments.

Comment: @CássioRenan `template< class InputIt, class OutputIt, class UnaryPredicate > OutputIt copy_if( InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first, UnaryPredicate pred );` The predicate is `pred`, which is a normal value argument. Its type is generic (a template parameter, `UnaryPredicate`), but the predicate itself is a normal value (either a function pointer or an instance of a class).

Comment: @melpomene class keyword in template is another name for typename, which is nothing but a type parameter and not a value parameter.

Comment: @AbhishekTripathi Dude, what. The predicate is `pred`, not `UnaryPredicate`. `UnaryPredicate` is just the name of the type of `pred`.

Comment: @melpomene Gotchu, my bad. Sorry. So, its nothing but either a class instance or   a pointer to a function, which in this case is pointer to some type.

Comment: @CássioRenan I mean neither of those. I mean *not a template parameter*, as in it's part of the normal function parameter list `(...)`, not the template parameter list `template< ... >`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's inspect a simple definition:

```
template <typename T>
struct TD;

bool is_odd(const int x) {
    return x % 2 != 0;
}

template<typename T>
void foo(T arg){
    TD<T> type_displayer;
}

int main() {
    foo(is_odd);
}
```

When you run this code, you get an error. An error saying that:

> '`TD<bool (*)(int)>` type_displayer' has incomplete type

That's my favourite 'hack' to inspect the deduced type (`T` from `foo`s argument). You can clearly see how I passed a function to `foo` in `main`, but the deduced type was `<bool (*)(int)>`, which is a *pointer to a function that returns `bool` and takes an `int` as argument*.

That's all it is to passing a function as an argument to a template function.

For references on *function pointers*, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654908/explanation-of-function-pointers) and [this tutorial](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/78-function-pointers/).

Comment: I think `is_even` would be a better function name...
EDIT: it would have been prior to the edit

Comment: @schulmaster I **really** should stop writing SO answers at 2 AM... Thank you for pointing that mistake!