# How does godot's NetSocket creates an instance?

Tags: c++, godot

I'm reading  the source code of [godot](https://github.com/godotengine/godot), and I can't understand how NetSocket class creates its instance.

In [net_socket.cpp](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/master/core/io/net_socket.cpp), create() is defined, but I can't see how it works.

```
#include "net_socket.h"

NetSocket *(*NetSocket::_create)() = NULL;

NetSocket *NetSocket::create() {

    if (_create)
        return _create();

    ERR_PRINT("Unable to create network socket, platform not supported");
    return NULL;
}
```

Especially, what is `_create`? And what does `NetSocket *(*NetSocket::_create)() = NULL;` do actually?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654908/explanation-of-function-pointers - not exactly a duplicate, but it should get you started :)

Comment: Please show `_create()` - without it the question is not answerable.

Comment: _@42milez_ Check where in the source code the `NetSocket::_create` function pointer is set to a specific function. It sounds like there are several platform specific implementations for that function (most probably in classes derived from `NetSocket`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong file. That one just delegates to whatever platform-specific implementation has been linked in/instantiated, using a *function pointer* called `_create`.

It is set in, for example, [the POSIX impl](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/master/drivers/unix/net_socket_posix.cpp).

Simply search the codebase for instances of `_create` and you'll see how it works.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the implementation.

Comment: @42milez Nice one. Further reading, maybe: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: I hadn't known pointer-to-member-function at all, but I got a new technique because of your help. Thank you :)